# How to insert values selected from multi select dropdown in users table Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to to insert multiple selected values while registering a user. I am able to insert single value from other dropdown fields in same form but it's not working when I am trying to insert multiple values. Can someone suggest what I need to do here

Here is my Register.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Org2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Org3</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="Org3[]" id="Org3" multiple class="form-control">
                                    @foreach($Org3_list as $use)
                                    @if(!empty($use))
                                    <option value="{{$use->CurrOrg3}}">{{$use->CurrOrg3}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                </select>

                                @error('Org3')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And this is my RegisterController:

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'Org1' => [ 'string'],
            'Org2' => ['string'],
            'Org3' => ['string'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'Org1' => $data['Org1'],
            'Org2' => $data['Org2'],
            'Org3' => $data['Org3'],
        ]);
        Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));

        return $user;
    }
```

Any help how to insert multiple values selected from dropdown.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the actual error please?

Comment: Only the First selected value is getting inserted, and I want to insert multiple selected values comma separated in database @toyi

Answer (score 0):

`Org3` isn't a `string`, it is an `array` so you need to handle it as such.

When validating `Org3` you want to check that it is an array. Note that you might want to validate other aspects of the array such as a `min` length, or you might accept `nullable`. Additionally, you might want to check the value of each element in the `Org3` array (never blindly assume input is going to be valid).

```
// validate that Org3 is an array
'Org3' => ['array'],

// validate that each element in Org3 is a string an exists in a database table
'Org3.*' => ['string', 'exists:table'],
```

There are other checks you could perform but you can do some searching for those.

Assuming validation is successful you then need to save `Org3` to the database.

One option would be to use [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on the array and then store the result to the database as a delimiter separated string:

```
implode(',', $request->Org3);
```

The issue I have with option one is that it's clunky when you want to search for a `User` based on one of multiple possible values a `User` has for `Org3`.

Option two would be to create a relationship between `User` and `Org3` and then store each value of `Org3` as a record of that relationship. This is a little more work but arguably more practical.

**Update 1**

As you're just wanting to insert into your database using a delimiter string, you could do the following:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'Org1' => [ 'string'],
        'Org2' => ['string'],
        'Org3' => ['array'],
        'Org3.*' => ['string'],
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'Org1' => $data['Org1'],
        'Org2' => $data['Org2'],
        'Org3' => implode(',', $data['Org3']),
    ]);
    Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

I've not done much in terms of validation, that's up to you to decide what is or is not appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Thanks..I am getting this error now " Array to string conversion"  when I am using array

Comment: Can you guide me where I need to modify in above code?

Comment: @prashant I have added an update with some example code.